# IAR linker CRC32 calculation doesn't match with the one calculated in C (and in other webs)

Tags: c, crc32, iar

The point is that I need to calculate a 32 bit CRC using the IAR in order to auto store this value into a known memory address but the result given by IAR and the one I calculate using a C function (checked using some online calculators) don't match. 
In the next paragraphs I will try to go step by step following all the process I followed.

I configured the IAR linker as it is recommended ( I think so at least ) in the following link:
[IAR documentation CRC links](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/checksum-calculation-with-ielftool-after-linking-with-ilink/)
The fact is that I have configured it as in the Calculate CRC32 as in STM32 hardware (v.5.50 and later) example (the first part of this, because I have IAR 6.5).
As I see there I tried to clone the configuration shown in the screenshot:
[CONFIGURATION PICTURE](https://www.iar.com/contentassets/d8bbf6cb53c44ac39f10798d3c086d67/64424-projectoptionslinkerchecksum_6_40.png)

And this is the configuration I use in my C CRC file:

```
/* PARAMETERS EXPLANATION
   * 'order' [1..32] is the CRC polynom order, counted without the leading
   * '1' bit.
   * 'polynom' is the CRC polynom without leading '1' bit.
   * 'direct' [0,1] specifies the kind of algorithm: 1=direct, no augmented
   * zero bits.
   * 'crcinit' is the initial CRC value belonging to that algorithm.
   * 'crcxor' is the final XOR value.
   * 'refin' [0,1] specifies if a data byte is reflected before processing
   * (UART) or not.
   * 'refout' [0,1] specifies if the CRC will be reflected before XOR.
   */

  /* Init parameters for CRC 32 algorithm */
  crcParams.order    = 32;
  crcParams.polynom  = 0x4C11DB7;
  crcParams.direct   = true;
  crcParams.crcinit  = 0xffffffff;
  crcParams.crcxor   = 0xffffffff;
  crcParams.refin    = false;
  crcParams.refout   = false;
```

I had a doubt about if the crcxor should be 0xFFFFFFFF or 0x00000000, but I tried with both without getting the expected result.

In order to check that the C function was working I have used the following websites:

[FIRST CRC32 CALCULATOR](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html)

[SECOND CRC32 CALCULATOR](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html)

The C code I use to calculate the CRC is based in the one explained here:
[CRC C code](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crctester.c)

This is an example of the configuration used in one of the websites:
[image: CRC CONFIGURATION BASED ON THE STM32 EXAMPLE]

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Best regrads.

Iván

Comment: I have also tried to implement the C code given by IAR in the following link https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/c-source-for-crc32/
But it doesn't work also.

Comment: Their [little CRC debugging tutorial](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/debugging-checksum-calculations/) is actually very good. You should look at that.

Comment: The most likely source of the problem (there are other possibilities) is the different codes are using different 'polynomials'

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this. I used this CRC32 code adapted to my purpose:
https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/c-source-for-crc32/

In all my other attempts I used the right Polynomial and tried all the configurations used with other boards in the IAR linker checksum configuration but those didn't work. So the configuration I used was with a init value of 0xFFFFFFFF and the following IAR linker configuration:

[image]

I hope this helps. It was very rare because of the problems I had implementing the other, I think valid, CRC32 implementations.

Best regards,

Iván

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that [their code](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/c-source-for-crc32/) is not working? What is your test case?

It is a CRC-32 that uses the polynomial `0x04c11db7` in a forward direction, with the initial CRC equal to `0xc704dd7b` and no final exclusive-or'ing. So `fast_crc32(0xc704dd7b, data, length)` will return the CRC  of `data[0..length-1]`.